# Grails Project Not Auto Reloading

Tags: grails

I have a larger Grails project for which I have taken over development. I have used Grails before and one of the features that I found really nice-to-have is the auto-compilation/reloading when developing.

I haven't had to do anything special to make this work in the past, however for some reason it is not triggered for this project.

I do a simple "grails run-app" and modify a file when server is started - nothing! Any suggestions?

Windows 7, Grails 2.0.1, Java 1.6u35

IDE: Groovy Grails Tool Suite 3.1.0.M1 - Based on Eclipse Juno 4.2

Comment: I have seen this, if you google it you'll see that it's a bug (if I remember it correctly).

What IDE are you using?

Comment: Edited. GGTS 3.1.0.M1 - BASED ON ECLIPSE JUNO 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Grails command line doesn't seem to properly handle spaces in directory names of GRAILS_HOME or HOME directory.

see:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7936

it has links to various other related issues.

This comment has a workaround: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7936?focusedCommentId=72170&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-72170 .

Comment: It certainly could be related, however the fix doesn't  do it for me, also, the error described in the related issue, is slightly different than mine. It states that the console displays "Compiling xx source files..." but the server is newer "reloaded".. Mine doesn't even trigger the "Compiling .." part in the console...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `eventCompileStart` in `scripts/_Events.groovy`? That was my problem, see [GRAILS-8776](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8776) (please comment and vote on that issue if this is your problem so we can get it resolved!).

Commenting out that block cause auto-reloading to start working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Right click on project -> Properties -> Project Facets -> check **Java** and set it's correct version -> OK

Bingo!