# How do I make grails run-app recompile files as they are changed?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I thought this was the default behavior, but I have noticed that changed Groovy files don't seem to be auto recompiled.

I'm using Grails 2.3.0

Comment: What version of Grails you are using ?

Comment: How do you run your grails application? Do you use interactive mode?

Comment: @baxxabit I just type `grails run-app` on terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try in console `grails` and then, in interactive mode, run-app

Comment: @baxxabit do you get auto-compilation by default?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel, yes, but I always use grails and then run-app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions is answered very clearly at [Grails 2.3.0 Auto-reloading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working).

Simply use `grails -reloading run-app` but follow the link get info how to enable forking as well.