# Grails ReloadingException when changing a service method's name

Tags: grails, spring-loaded

I am using Grails 2.3.8

When I change a method's name in a service class, and try to invoke it I get an error similar to this:

```
org.springsource.loaded.ReloadException: ReloadableType.determineDispatcher(): expected com.SomeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a85275cb to be reloadable
```

Now I guess this is because the actual service class is being wrapped in spring's "enhancer" and this somehow makes it unreloadable, but I'm not exactly sure why, and I have not found any information concerning this.

Is there a workaround for this, or do I have to restart the application whenever I change a method's name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the reloadable warnings in grails console, follow these steps:

1. Download the springloaded-1.2.0 from here: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.0.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
2. Copy this jar to grails-2.3.7/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars
3. Edit grails-2.3.7/bin/startGrails file, search for AGENT_STRING  and change the AGENT_STRING to point to it rather than the 1.1.5 included in the distribution. It should look like this:

   set AGENT_STRING=-javaagent:"%GRAILS_HOME:\=/%/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar" -noverify -Dspringloaded=\"%SPRINGLOADED_PARAMS%\"
4. restart grails

Comment: This is interesting. It works as expected, but throws the following error:
`Plugin [services:2.3.8] could not reload changes to file [/SomeService.groovy]: Cannot get property 'cacheOperationSource' on null object [ERROR][org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager]`

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 2.3 reloading is enabled using the grails command:

```
grails -reloading run-app
```

Or you can set

```
grails.reload.enabled = true
```

in BuildConfig.groovy

Both these approaches are not perfect. Look here for more reference:

https://grails.org/Auto+Reloading

[Grails 2.3.0 Auto-reloading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working)

Comment: I have reloading enabled, it works in most cases.

I've also noticed the remark in the documentation about typed vs untyped injection, and I've tried both, but neither worked.