# Hot code fix is compiling but not picking in grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails

Created a new app in grails 2.4.4, and created one controller and gsp file. while in development running mode I am changing the code- the gsp file changes are reflecting in the browser but not the controller code, but in both cases I am getting message

```
Applying changes to application.
| Compiling 1 source files.
```

My 1) Buildconfig.groovy and 2. Config.groovy file is listed below

1) BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

2. Config.groovy

   // locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
       // config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
       // in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

   ```
   // grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
   //                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
   //                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
   //                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

   // if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
   //    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
   // }

   grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination

   // The ACCEPT header will not be used for content negotiation for user agents containing the following strings (defaults to the 4 major rendering engines)
   grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
   grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
       all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
       atom:          'application/atom+xml',
       css:           'text/css',
       csv:           'text/csv',
       form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
       js:            'text/javascript',
       json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
       multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
       rss:           'application/rss+xml',
       text:          'text/plain',
       hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
       xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
   ]

   // URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
   //grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

   // Legacy setting for codec used to encode data with ${}
   grails.views.default.codec = "html"

   // The default scope for controllers. May be prototype, session or singleton.
   // If unspecified, controllers are prototype scoped.
   grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

   // GSP settings
   grails {
       views {
           gsp {
               encoding = 'UTF-8'
               htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
               codecs {
                   expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                   scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                   taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
                   staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
               }
           }
           // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
           // filteringCodecForContentType.'text/html' = 'html'
       }
   }


   grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
   // scaffolding templates configuration
   grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

   // Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
   grails.json.legacy.builder = false
   // enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
   grails.enable.native2ascii = true
   // packages to include in Spring bean scanning
   grails.spring.bean.packages = []
   // whether to disable processing of multi part requests
   grails.web.disable.multipart=false

   // request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
   grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

   // configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
   grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

   // configure passing transaction's read-only attribute to Hibernate session, queries and criterias
   // set "singleSession = false" OSIV mode in hibernate configuration after enabling
   grails.hibernate.pass.readonly = false
   // configure passing read-only to OSIV session by default, requires "singleSession = false" OSIV mode
   grails.hibernate.osiv.readonly = false
   grails.reload.enabled = true
   environments {
       development {
           grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
       }
       production {
           grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
           // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
       }
   }

   // log4j configuration
   log4j.main = {
       // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
       //
       //appenders {
       }

       error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
              'org.springframework',
              'org.hibernate',
              'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
   }
   ```
3. Added a line in index.gsp:

[Click](http://checkNew/student/blankAction)

4. created controller name Student

   package project.bidesi.check
   class StudentController {
       def index() { }

   ```
   def blankAction(){
       render(view:"/student/blankAction", model:[mineData:"ppppp"])
   }
   ```

   }
5. created gsp name blankAction.gsp

   Sample title

   ## Sample line

   ${mineData}

so when i am changing the value of mineData in the controller its not reflecting in gsp, but in output prompt i am getting message like:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/checkNew
| Compiling 1 source files.
```

Even though i tried with the command

```
grails -reloading run-app
```

but it does not help.

Comment: please provide a full example.  or at least the controller and what changes are not picked up.

Comment: controller and gsp code added

Answer (score 1):

It appears your problem is in the grails.project.fork setting.   I'd suggest explicitly setting your fork settings as per here  [Grails 2.3.0 Auto-reloading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working)