# Grails 2.5.1 reloading not working

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

After building project in Grails 2.5.1 reloading is not working. After some changes in controller, service or in my own groovy classes, I've to restart the application to see the changes. I've used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working), but having the same behaviour.

In the console I'm getting an error-

```
plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager - Plugin [controllers:2.5.1] could not reload changes to file [***.groovy]: Cannot get property 'cacheOperationSource' on null object.
```

Have any ideas?

Comment: maybe it depend's on cache:1.1.8 plugin?

Comment: Have grails in your package or naming convention : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/u5gvuwWXoTk ...... 
In the app you sent me you had the package name for the Service class as package: grails.slow2
Now if I am corrent, it seems that grails has a plugin manager that caches all files in a grails.* package name or folder to make reloads faster. Hence your service class was cached since the package name had grails keyword in the name.  .. change the package name ...and the reload worked just perfectly. Please test this on your side and confirm this for me.

Comment: in my all packages i haven't package grails...

Comment: Same problem i am facing. Have you found any solution.Even "grails -reloading run-app" is not working and forked execution is available by default.